# Parsing the exact match in a text file using a PHP

Tags: php

I’m new to PHP and trying to parse the exact sentence in a text file using PHP function preg_grep(). As you can see below it prints out everything close but not exactly. For example “[40]=>will this work?” also prints out a “?” which isn’t in the variable ‘$sta’ . How do you find and retrieve the correct strings?

```
$lines = file("{$dir}/status.txt");

$sta=”will this work”;

$data = preg_grep("/$sta/", $lines);


print_r($data)

( [40] => S9477 will this work? 21/09/2014 

 [41] => S9487  will this work  21/09/2013 

 [42] => S9497  will this work  05/06/2002 )

)
```

Comment: You would be better off doing `preg_match` most likely, you have more control perhaps.

Comment: Change `/$sta/` to `/ $sta /`?